# The type or namespace SpeechRecognition does not exist in the namespace Windows.Media -- Universal Application (Windows 8.1)

Tags: c#, speech-recognition, microsoft-band

I'm trying to build an app that combines speech recognition with an interface to the Microsoft Band. I want to use speech to drive a laptop-based program, and that program to drive data streaming from the Band.

The Band SDK works with a Universal App template for Windows Phone 8.1, and I have been able to stream data from the Band to a laptop (running either Windows 8.1 or 10) using the Windows 8.1 project in the UA solution (I haven't tried the Phone 8.1 project, yet, but have seen demos of this online).

I have found that the UA template won't let me add references, and System.Speech is unsupported. Windows.Media.SpeechSynthesis is supported (the 'using' clause is accepted), but Windows.Media.SpeechRecognition is not (the 'using' clause throws the error message).

Is there a work-around for getting the SpeechRecognition dll to be recognised, or has Microsoft simply decided not to allow speech recognition to work with the Universal App template?

(Maybe the Band has been cancelled because they just don't know how to engineer everything to play together?)

Answer (score 0):

Did you read MSDN, info about [System.Speech.Recognition](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.speech.recognition(v=vs.110).aspx)? I had just create simple ConsoleApplication, add Reference to System.Speech and everythink work fine:
[image]

Comment: Did you read my question?  The namespace System.Speech.Recognition is available to a console application, so of course your test app works. My problem is that it is not recognised in an app based on a Windows Runtime template, which I am forced to use in order to support the Band API. I am looking for a way to implement speech recognition in that environment (and wasting a lot of time, thanks to Microsoft's own confusion).